# ASP .NET Core IIS Support often hangs / how enable log

Tags: asp.net-core

I use [IIS Support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/development-time-iis-support)  at development-time.

Its works.

But often are hangs.

I kill the "dotnet" process and continue work

**How solve a hangs?**

**How enable logs to detect problem?**

Answer (score 1):

I am not really sure what you mean with the term **hangs** but if you want to enable logging on **IIS** please take a look at the following [post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module). At a minimum, change the **stdoutLogEnabled** property to true and do not forget to manually create a folder called **logs** at the same level as the **web.config** file.